# WPF grid size changed event firing only when increasing and not when decreasing

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, stackpanel

I have a grid with rowdefinitions

```
RowDefinition rd0 = new RowDefinition();
rd0.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
RowDefinition rd1 = new RowDefinition();
rd1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
RowDefinition rd2 = new RowDefinition();
rd2.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto);
grdMain.RowDefinitions.Add(rd0);
grdMain.GetGrdPlugins().RowDefinitions.Add(rd1);
grdMain.GetGrdPlugins().RowDefinitions.Add(rd2);
```

now in the first row I add a textblock

```
var tbxTitle = new TextBlock(){};
Grid.SetRow(tbxTitle, 0);
grdMain.Children.Add(tbxTitle);
```

in the third a stack panel of buttons

```
StackPanel spButtons = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, };
grdMain.Children.Add(spButtons);
Grid.SetRow(spButtons, 2);
...
```

in the second a stackpanel.

Now I want an event to be called all the times the grid changes in size:

```
var spMatrix_Volatile = new StackPanel() { HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, Background = Brushes.RosyBrown};
spMatrix_Volatile.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.Beep();
    double dHeight = spMatrix_Volatile.ActualHeight;
    CreateCellMatrix(out strResult, ref spMatrix_Volatile, false, dHeight);
};

Grid.SetRow(spMatrix_Volatile, 1);
grdMain.Children.Add(spMatrix_Volatile);
```

now the peculiar thing is that the size changed event is called all the times the height of the grid is increased but never when decreased.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens to me as well using your code. 
I have therefore put the stackpanel in a grid and that didn't happen anymore.
That is the event is fired both when increasing and decreasing.